# iOS not showing Rich Notification

Tags: ios, remote-notifications

I am using sailThru in my iOS app, i need to show Rich Notification when triggered from sailThru dashboard. But notification arrives as simple push, instead it should arrive as Rich notification.

Also, `override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)` of `UNNotificationServiceExtension` doesn't gets called.

Please help me, why it doesn't get called.
Thanks

Comment: Make sure your payload contains `content-available : 1`

Comment: May i know did u use notification extension for RICH notification . 1. https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios-10-day-by-day-day-6-notification-content-extensions . 2. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/creating-ios-rich-push-notifications

Answer (score 0):

If you believe everything is fully-setup such as the payload that your server is passing to your app (not to mention Krishna's comment, payload should include: `content-available : 1`), `NotificationServiceExtension`, `NotificationContentExtension`, and whatnot, then there should be no problem.

Now, to get the `override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)` method triggered (such as triggering your breakpoint in there), you need to run your app using your **NotificationService** target.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am running using "RichNotificationExtension" as target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should check is that your NotificationServiceExtension is not taking too much memory (RAM) as it runs on a separate process and it can be killed by the OS if it takes more than few Mb.
Console app can be helpful to debug this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get Rich Notification make sure to add "mutable_content" key in the payload, also we need to configure all required UNUserNotification settings to achieve this.

I got to fixed this.